# Duda con la sentencia INSERT MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, insert

En la sentencia `INSERT INTO` es obligatorio escribir todos los campos la tabla sin importar que todos los valores (variables) en el campo `VALUE` no reciban datos.

Ejemplo

```
$conexion->query( "INSERT INTO $ejemp (casa, color, estrato, barrio, carro) VALUES ('$casa','$color','$estrato','$calle','$carro')" );
```

la tabla `ejemp` tiene 5 campos, pero solo reciben datos de un formulario el campo `casa`, `color`, `estrato`. los demás no.

La pregunta es porque tengo una base de datos en un servidor web y agregue 3 nuevas columnas la cual hasta que no modifique el `INSERT INTO` no insertaba ningún dato, pero tenia una tabla en `XAMPP` con campos que no estaban `INSERT` y si registraba los datos que se enviaban.

Alguien puede aclarar ese punto ya que estuve leyendo pero la mayoría de documentación esta en inglés.

---EDITO----

A todos gracias por responder.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los campos en rojos (3 ultimos de la imagen) no estan en el `INSERT` pero tampoco en el `VALUE`, es decir tenia 23 items en el `INSERT` y 23 Items en el VALUE. mi intención era llenar los 3 últimos campos con otro formulario con un `UPDATE` Antes de que esos 3 últimos campos estuvieran en la tabla se insertaban los datos, después de anexar esos 3 columnas ya no. Lo que hice fue escribir los valores en el `INSERT` y las variables en el `VALUE` aunque no recibían datos, y había `INSERT` de los datos enviados.

el codigo era este

```
$conexion->query( "INSERT INTO $tabla_db1 (submission_id, pedido, fecha, seleccionael6, valorfonendo, lodeseas, seleccionael25, totalart, abonofonendos, abonoaccesorios, envio, valorabono, fechalimite, total, nombre, documento, celular, correoelectronico, direccionde, ciudad, departamento, comentarios, texto_a) VALUES ('$id','$pedido','$fecha','$fonendo','$valor_fdo','$marcar','$articulo','$total_art','$abono_f','$abono_a','$envio','$abono','$limite','$total','$nombre','$doc','$cel','$mail','$dir','$city','$dpto','$info','$texto_a')" );
```

Comment: Varias cosas intervienen: 1. Si en el INSERT tienes 5 columnas debes tener también 5 valores, aunque algunos de ellos sean nulos. 2. Si el diseño de la tabla admite valores nulos para los valores que no sean llenados en el formulario no habrá problemas , pero tú en el código debes indicar que en el caso de no haber valores inserte NULL o 0 o una cadena vacía (las tres cosas no son lo mismo )... Ahora bien, si alguna de esas columnas está declarada como NOT NULL, el INSERT fallará. 3. Para hacer este tipo de operaciones es más fácil, más limpio y más seguro usar consultas preparadas.

Comment: @A.Cedano Considero que deberías de pasar ese comentario a respuesta con un poco más de desarrollo sobre el tema. Huelga decir (y seguro que tu también lo sabes) que responder en un comentario no se considera una buena práctica ya que no es el propósito del comentario y evita que añadan respuestas.

Comment: @frikinside Hay momentos en los que no puedes elaborar una buena respuesta (ejemplo cuando estás desde el teléfono móvil), ya que dar una respuesta documentada se complica. En cuanto esté en un entorno más favorable daré una respuesta un poco más detallada con ejemplos. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano mejor comentemos esto en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60876/discusion-a-cedano-y-frikinside)

Comment: @Daniel es posible que edites la preguntas y agreges tu diseño de la tabla solo como la tienes estructurada porque como comento Mary Rios es posible esto **Podría deberse a que al agregar la columna le permitiste valores nulos o si no los permitiste le pusiste un valor por default

**

Comment: a todos gracias por sus repuestas

Comment: Es lo que te decía en mi respuesta. Si los últimos tres campos que has creado no admiten nulos, el hecho de **omitirlos** en una sentencia `INSERT` sería el equivalente a tratar de introducir valores nulos en ellos, tendrías el error: `Field 'nombredecolumna' doesn't have a default value`. A no ser que dichas columnas tengan un valor predeterminado, el cual tendrían en el caso de no estar en la sentencia `INSERT` (esto último no lo he probado, ahora lo pruebo y edito mi respuesta).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La [documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) dice lo siguiente sobre las consultas del tipo `INSERT INTO ...`:

> Las columnas para las que la sentencia proporciona valores se pueden
>   especificar de la siguiente manera:
>
> - Puede proporcionar **una lista separada por comas de nombres de columna después del nombre de la tabla**. En este caso, **un valor
>     para cada columna nombrada debe ser proporcionado** por la lista
>     `VALUES` o la instrucción `SELECT`.
> - **Si no especifica una lista de nombres de columna** para `INSERT ... VALUES` o `INSERT ... SELECT`, **los valores de cada columna de la
>     tabla deben proporcionarse mediante la lista `VALUES` o la sentencia
>     `SELECT`**. Si no conoce el orden de las columnas en la tabla, use
>     `DESCRIBE tbl_name` para averiguarlo.

La segunda opción significa, en otras palabras, que puedes escribir una sentencia como esta:

```
INSERT INTO tu_tabla VALUES ('valor-columna1-varchar', valor-columna2-int ...)
```

Como se puede ver, no aparece la lista de columnas a la izquierda de `VALUES`... en ese caso se debe proporcionar un valor para cada columna en el orden en que las mismas están definidas en la tabla, pasando este valor según el tipo de la columna (varchar, int, etc).

Aunque esto se puede hacer, lo normal es construir nuestro `INSERT` como se indica en la 1ª opción, es decir, indicar de forma explícita a la izquierda de `VALUES` los nombres de las columnas donde queremos insertar los datos y a la derecha de `VALUES` los valores que queremos insertar.

Para responder a tu pregunta:

> En la sentencia `INSERT INTO` es obligatorio escribir todos los campos
>   de la tabla sin importar que todos los valores (variables) en el campo
>   VALUE no reciban datos.

Supongamos una tabla como esta:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
    ejemplo_insert (
         id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
         nombre VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
         apellido VARCHAR (50),
         documento VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '**********'
       );
```

Veamos ahora varios casos.

---

#### Caso 1: todo normal... como debe ser

Si escribes una consulta como esta para insertar datos en la tabla anterior:

```
INSERT INTO ejemplo_insert 
    (nombre, apellido) VALUES ('Pedro','Pérez');
```

Es obligatorio pasar a la consulta **un valor para la columna `nombre` y otro valor para la columna `apellido`**. Aquí se omite la columna `documento` en la instrucción SQL, pero los datos se insertan, porque dicha columna tiene definido un valor predeterminado, el cual asumirá al crearse el registro.

---

#### Caso 2: No tan normal... pero funciona

```
INSERT INTO ejemplo_insert 
    (nombre, apellido) VALUES ('','Pérez');
```

Esta consulta funcionaría, porque estás introduciendo en `nombre` datos en blanco, que no es lo mismo que nulo.

---

#### Caso 3: Tampoco tan normal, pero funciona

```
INSERT INTO ejemplo_insert 
    (nombre, apellido) VALUES ('Pedro',NULL);
```

También funciona, porque en este caso la columna `apellido` sí admite nulos.

---

#### Caso 4: Omitiendo el valor de una columna indicada en la lista

Si escribes una consulta así:

```
INSERT INTO ejemplo_insert 
    (nombre, apellido) VALUES ('Pedro');
```

Tendrás derecho al error siguiente en MySQL:

> ```
>  Column count doesn't match value count
> ```

Es decir, *¡me dijiste que iba a introducir datos en dos columnas, pero me estás dando datos de una solamente!*.

---

#### Caso 5: Tratar de introducir un valor nulo en una columna que no admite nulos

Otra cosa que puede ocurrir es que intentes introducir un valor nulo `NULL`, en una columna que no admite nulos. Por ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO ejemplo_insert 
    (nombre, apellido) VALUES (NULL,'Pérez');
```

Aquí tendrás derecho al error siguiente:

> ```
> Column 'nombre' cannot be null
> ```

Si ves el `CREATE TABLE` de más arriba entenderás el motivo de esta protesta del sistema :)

Sin embargo, en el caso 2 no dio error, porque se introdujo un valor en blanco, no un nulo, porque `NULL` y  no es lo mismo.

---

#### Caso 6: Omitir en la sentencia SQL una columna que no admite nulos y que al mismo tiempo no tiene definido un valor por defecto

En la siguiente consulta:

```
INSERT INTO ejemplo_insert 
    (apellido) VALUES ('Pérez');
```

Vas a merecer el error siguiente:

```
Field 'nombre' doesn't have a default value
```

Porque omitiste de la sentencia SQL la columna `nombre` la cual, ni admite nulos ni tiene un valor por defecto. Verás que no ha ocurrido lo mismo con la columna `documento` la cual ha sido omitida en esta y otras instrucciones de inserción. ¿Por qué no reclama nada con respecto a `documento` y sí con respecto a `nombre`? Porque como `documento` tiene definido un valor por defecto, las nuevas filas creadas asumen dicho valor cuando la columna es omitida en cualquier sentencia.

---

#### [`VER DEMO DEL CÓDIGO`](http://rextester.com/CPJ19989)

---

### Recomendación

Es fuertemente recomendado el uso de consultas preparadas en todos los manejos de base de datos que incluyan datos desde el exterior, ya que enviar consultas *enteras*, es decir, en las que va toda la instrucción, es una puerta abierta a la Inyección SQL. Lo que hacen las consultas preparadas es separar los datos de la instrucción SQL en sí, dando más seguridad e incluso facilidad al código.

Ver al respecto:

- [Stackoverflow: ¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967)
- [Manual de PHP: Sentencias preparadas y procedimientos almacenados](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, leeré al respecto de consultas preparadas, ya que bastante inexperto en el tema

Comment: @Daniel, he editado la respuesta, después de ver tu sentencia de inserción completa, se puede ver con claridad que tu problema está definido en el **caso 6** de mi respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo, efectivamente, cambie el campo a nullo y sin modificar la sentencia inserto los datos enviados.

Comment: Cedeño una ultima duda, como hago para que en el error que tenia el php me muestre ` 'nombredecolumna' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: Ese error, cuando ocurra, se verá en el `error_log` de PHP, si tienes las notificaciones de error activadas tanto en PHP como en MySQL al hacer la conexión.

Comment: en su momento busque en el  `error_log` y me mostro notice and warnings pero no ese error e inlcuso le tengo este codigo `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` pero no la tengo en el php de abrir_conexion.php lo  adicionare y te comentare

Comment: @Daniel Advierto que si usas PDO debes ser muy cuidadoso con la notificación de errores, ya que si no lo haces bien y hay un fallo al crear la conexión a PDO, se muestran en el `error_log` las credenciales de conexión: usuario, contraseña, etc. El `error_log` se puede leer con suma facilidad y es uno de los archivos favoritos de los hackers. Para evitarlo lo mejor es tener una Clase que maneje las conexiones, colocando en el método de conexión el atributo propio para un manejo seguro de los errores.

Answer (score 0):

Podría deberse a que al agregar la columna le permitiste valores nulos o si no los permitiste le pusiste un valor por default